# Setting UiButton image after converting PHAsset to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage, phasset

Hi I am using following code to fetch the last image from photo library and then setting it to button but it turns out to be showing the default color grey instead of the image

```
func loadLastImageThumb(completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
 // fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1
   fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate",  ascending: true)]
  let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: fetchOptions)

if let last = fetchResult.lastObject {
   let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
    options.resizeMode = .exact
    options.isSynchronous = true
    options.version = .original
    print(last)
    imgManager.requestImage(for: last, targetSize: gallery.bounds.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, _) in
        if let image = image {
            completion(image)
            print(image)
            print(image.size)
            print(self.gallery.bounds.size)

        }
    })
}
}
```

//in view did load

```
   self.loadLastImageThumb { [weak self] (image) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self?.gallery.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you doing it on main thread?

Comment: From your print statements I guess you've tried debugging and found you are getting an image, correct? Does it display in a regular UIImageView?

Comment: I am able to get the image object using the above code. It seems like problem is with image showing on `UIImageView`. Check outlet of image view, and retrieved image size(if should not be 0, 0).

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal it's not in the image view, its an outlet of a button as m setting image of the button from this

Comment: @dfd this is what i get when i print uiimage <UIImage: 0x1d00b8f60>, {68, 120}

Comment: Please check if you are using `clickButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)` not `clickButton.imageView.image = image`.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal check my code and m using //  self?.gallery.setImage(image, for: .normal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will be
`self?.gallery.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)`